# Knex: Can you do a then after an update?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Using Knex, I'd like to do an update and then perform some other action, preferably using the results from the update. The following did not appear to put anything in the console.

```
db('challenges').where('challenged', '=', challengedName)
  .update( {
    userA: chal[0].challenged,
    userB: chal[0].challenger
  })
  .then(function(dosomething) {
    console.log("You can do a then after an update");
    console.dir(dosomething);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

The update worked as I looked in the DB and the results I expect are there. I'm not sure why the console.* aren't firing though.

Comment: Ok, I added a `.returning` to the update and it works. My question is why? Is `.update` a terminating command that can't have anything after it if there's no `.returning`?

Comment: Just an additional note as I try different things: it doesn't appear I can use `.returning('*')` to get all the fields. I guess if I want everything, I have to explicitly list them.